# How can I make my if statement work with this script?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I posted about this question yesterday, but everybody suggested that I use the BeautifulSoup lib. I'm not allowed to use any external libs for class, but I've gotten a bit farther. The code should open the given website, and append any of the information between header tags. This is an introductory class, so I understand that I may be asking something that's pretty simple. How can I fix any syntax errors? The particular issue lies after my "findHeader" variable is declared.

Edit:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\website header search.py", line 16, in 
    if (findHeader, headerEnd) in line:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
address = "http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/"
webPage = urlopen (address)

list = []

encoding = "utf-8"
for line in webPage:
    line = str(line, encoding)
    findHeader = ('h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6')
    headerEnd = ('/h1', '/h2', '/h3', '/h4', '/h5', '/h6')
    if (findHeader, headerEnd) in line:
        start = line.index(findHeader, headerEnd) + len(findHeader, headerEnd)
        last = line.index('"', start)
        list.append(line[start : last])

webPage.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another very simple solution to the problem. I believe you want to search for matching headers (so for example `<h1>` and `</h1>` in the same line). This is a very basic solution that does not use any external library:

```
findHeader = ('<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>', '<h5>', '<h6>')

line = 'This is the <h1>header content</h1> and this is not'
for startHeader in findHeader:
    endHeader = '</'+startHeader[1:]
    if (startHeader in line) and (endHeader in line):
        content = line.split(startHeader)[1].split(endHeader)[0]
        print content
```

It prints out:

```
header content
```

To put it in your code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

address = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp"
webPage = urlopen (address)

encoding = "utf-8"

for line in webPage:
    findHeader = ('<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>', '<h5>', '<h6>')
    line = str(line, encoding)

    for startHeader in findHeader:        
        endHeader = '</'+startHeader[1:]
        if (startHeader in line) and (endHeader in line):
            content = line.split(startHeader)[1].split(endHeader)[0]
            print (content)



webPage.close()
```

Comment: @ toti08 This code does work when isolated. Any tips on how to connect it to the code I currently have? I've tried a few different things to no avail

Comment: OOps, sorry, I tested it in Python 2.7. I believe that's the reason it doesn't work....

Comment: Well as I said, the code itself works when you try to use it just as you posted, but I can't seem to substitute my line variable with yours.

Comment: Did you try just removing my test line and replacing the piece of code from where you define `findHeader` and so on?

Comment: that's what I currently have, I tried a few more things but cant remember everything I've tried

Comment: @ toti08 Hopefully fixed :)

Comment: Try and remove the line `line.index(findHeader)`

Comment: There is an indentation error in your code. The line `if (startHeader in line) and (endHeader in line):` and subsequent should be indented.

Comment: it works now. Thank you so much for the help! It's greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`if (findHeader, headerEnd) in line:` As the traceback says, you can't check if a tuple is in a string. I'm assuming you're trying to check if both of them are in the line. This is a job for `any`.

```
if any(header in line for header in (findHeader, headerEnd)):
    do_things
```

Answer (score 0):

If your case is that simply, i suggest using a simple regex.

```
import re

line = 'I am a <h1>jedi</h1> and you are not'
regex = re.compile('<h[0-9]>(.*)</h[0-9]>')
match = regex.search(line)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

it will return

```
jedi
```

Just for completeness, you cannot find a tuple in a string just as you cannot find a list in a string. If you really need to follow that approach you have to check each element inside the list against your line.

Answer (score 0):

Like your error message says:

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple

When saying, "*look for something in this string,*" it's expected that you are looking for a string within that string. If you want to check if a string (`line`) contains at least one of multiple possible options (`findHeader` *and/or* `headerEnd`), you should do some kind of iteration checking each option to see if it is present.

There any many ways you can handle this kind of iteration/check in Python. Some of them are one-line solutions and some of them take several lines. The way that's the most readable, in my opinion, is to actually write a loop to iterate through the list of possibilities (`findHeader`) and check if the values are present. If one of the values is present, exit the loop and check if the respective closing tag is present (`headerEnd`).

The following is a revision to your code to perform such a check in a very readable way:

```
for line in webPage.split("\n"):
    line = str(line, encoding)
    findHeader = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']
    headerEnd = ['/h1', '/h2', '/h3', '/h4', '/h5', '/h6']
    headerIndexNumber = -1
    for i in range(len(findHeader)):
        # Attempt to find the start of a header in the line
        if(( '<' + findHeader[i]) in line):
            # The line contains what appears to be the start of a header
            headerIndexNumber = i
            break
        # End if
    # End for

    # Check if the for loop above found a header index
    if(headerIndexNumber >= 0):
        # Great, we found a header index number in the line above
        # Now let's check for a respective closing tag.
        if(('<' + headerEnd[headerIndexNumber]) in line):
            # Cool, the line also appears to contain a closing tag for
            # the same type of header.

            ## ... <YOUR CODE HERE FOR DOING SOMETHING EITHER BETWEEN
            ## ...  OR WITH THE HTML HEADER TAGS> ...

        # End if(header closing tag was found in line)
    # End if(header start tag was found in line)
# End foreach loop (line in webPage)
```

Obviously, this is just a chunk of your code revised. If you decide to decide to go with this as your solution, you will need to place it in your existing code where it is relevant and you will still need to write the inner-logic (i.e., the code that handles what you do once a header tag is found to exist in the line).

Nonetheless, I have tried to write this code in a very readable and understandable way with comments that explain what each line does. If any thing in the code I have included above does not make sense, please leave a comment and I will try to explain it.

A few things to note about the provided code:

- I am doing `for line in webPage.split("\n")`. I tested this locally with `webPage` set to a string containing the raw HTML source of a webpage. Because of this, the webpage source needed to be split into individual lines otherwise the for-loop would just loop through every individual character in the webpage's HTML rather than the full lines. If that's not relevant to your code, simply remove the split command.
- When I am checking for header tags in the line, I am prepending `<` to the value I am looking for. This is because HTML tags always begin with `<`. So this will prevent a false-positive match if the line just contained "h1" written in it.

**EDIT**: In reference to your comment, OP, here is an easy way to print out the strings between the `h`-tags based on the code you posted to Pastebin:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
address = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp"
webPage = urlopen (address)

encoding = "utf-8"

list = []

for line in webPage:
    findHeader = ('<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>', '<h5>', '<h6>')
    line = str(line, encoding)
    for startHeader in findHeader:        
        endHeader = '</'+startHeader[1:]
        if (startHeader in line) and (endHeader in line):
            content = line.split(startHeader)[1].split(endHeader)[0]
            list.append(line)


for h in list:
    print((h[4:]).strip()[:-5])

webPage.close()
```

Comment: Someone had already posted a solution that did what I needed on a basic level, but there's a bit more to it to finalize what's done if you're interested in taking a look at it. http://pastebin.com/ua9hdw8u It prints everything I was looking for, but I need to omit the actual tags from the search, and it would probably be good to have every part of the list on a separate line. So for example, if the code were to find <h1>Python is fun</h1>, my list will simply say "Python is fun".

Comment: @Cameron, added a solution for that to my answer as an edit based on the code you have posted on PasteBin. Sorry for the delay in responding. I never saw the notification for your comment. Hopefully it'll be of some use to you still.